data return incorrect using left join with 2 tables
Not sure why use left join return multiple duplicate with 2 tables and return in correct data.
table1
emp  type
tom   1
tom   2

table2
emp  grade
tom   a
tom   b
tom   c

query look correct but still missing some thing

select table1.emp , table1.type, table2.emp, table2.grade
from table1
left join table2 on table1.emp = table2.emp


return
emp type    emp grade
tom 1       tom a         
tom 1       tom b         
tom 1       tom c         
tom 2       tom a         
tom 2       tom b         
tom 2       tom c  

Use left join  and return incorrect data and expect correct return
emp  type  grade
tom   1     a
tom   2     b
tom         c


Use ROW_NUMBER() window function as additional join condition.
Do FULL OUTER JOIN to handle different combinations of table1 and table2 number of rows.
select coalesce(t1.emp, t2.emp) emp, t1.type, t2.grade
from
  (select emp, type, row_number() over (partition by emp order by type) rn
   from table1) t1
full join
  (select emp, grade, row_number() over (partition by emp order by grade) rn
   from table2) t2
  on t1.emp = t2.emp and t1.rn = t2.rn


Excellent! Make sense get row and re-join

There are duplicates because LEFT JOIN combines every matching row from both tables. Because both of your tables have multiple rows for each "emp", it lists you every possible combination.
You can use DISTINCT to only show unique combinations:
SELECT DISTINCT table1.emp , table1.type, table2.emp, table2.grade
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.emp = table2.emp


Although a distinct could work, youre masking the results because the query and the data isnt the best
